# 419 Error Code While Making Post Request To Laravel From Android App

Tags: java, android, laravel

I am working with android app I have to use Laravel as backend. I am using Retrofit for GET and POST Requests.  It is working fine when I make some GET request but it show 419 error code when I try to make some POST request I searched about 419 error it is about page expired or Something about missing CSRF token. Any one can guide me how can we handle this error. How can get CSRF token and how to use it. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using web.php to write the API endpoints. That's why it's showing CSRF errors. Use api.php to write API endpoints. It doesn't require a CSRF token. When you write routes in api.php don't forget to add `/api` prefix.

Comment: can you define how to write this route Route::post('/saveUser', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'saveUser']); in api.php

Comment: you should write the same. Just copy paste the route. It will work. When you call the endpoint only you need to call like /api/saveUser